# Using pgfplots with raw gnuplot plotting commands, is it possible to reuse tikzpictures?

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I have a `main.tex` in which I import plots as tikzpictures with `includegraphics`. A typical plot looks like this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def \dataFile {'plots/data/sample_data.dat'}

  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot \dataFile index 0 };
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, I want to make a beamer presentation using the same tikzpictures. The `presentation.tex` file is located in a different folder entirely. I've updated my `graphicspath` accordingly, but when I want to include a tikzpicture, it cannot find the data file `sample_data.dat`, because gnuplot is being invocated in the folder of `presentation.tex`.

I couldn't find a way of setting the input directory to the pgfplots raw gnuplot command. Short of specifying every data file location as a full path, is there a clever way to solve this?